# How to play wma file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, wma

I want to build a radio app in iPhone for which wma streaming is necessary. So if u have any idea please help me.
  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gallagher published in his blog a [good tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) with code for playing MP3 streaming in iPhone. I don't know if it will work for WMA, however I think it's a good start point.